# Creating a flattened (panorama?) 2D view of a cubemap

Tags: opengl, glsl, python

I am trying to generate a 360 degree view of a scene by sampling a depth cubemap using spherical coordinates. x and y represent the horizontal, or azimuth, and elevation angles respectively and the actual value at each pixel is the depth.

Output: So far I have not been able to achieve this. I am not getting any errors just a blank 2D image.

Here are what I consider to be the essential parts of the process.
First creating a cubemap to store depth information,

```py
# CREATE EMPTY CUBEMAP
######################
CM = 2

depth_map_fbo = glGenFramebuffers(1)
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, depth_map_fbo)

depth_cube_tex = glGenTextures(1)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, depth_cube_tex)

for i in range(6):
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X+i, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32, CM*1024, CM*1024,
                    0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, None)

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST) # or GL_LINEAR?
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)

# attach depth texture to fbo depth buffer
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, depth_cube_tex, 0)
glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE)
glReadBuffer(GL_NONE)
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)
```

Second, obtaining depth information for a simple scene made out of 3 cubes and a floor,

```
# CREATE A DEPTH CUBE
#####################

                    # relative are not correct???
#                   pitch, yaw, rel_pitch, rel_yaw, name, location
rotation_dict= {0: [   0,  90,         0,      90, 'X+', 'Right'],
                1: [   0, -90,         0,    -180, 'X-', 'Left'],
                2: [  90, 180,       -90,      90, 'Y+', 'Top'],
                3: [ -90, 180,       180,       0, 'Y-', 'Bottom'],
                4: [   0,   0,       -90,     180, 'Z+', 'Back'],
                5: [   0, 180,         0,    -180, 'Z-', 'Front']}

# cubemap camera
cubemap_camera.width = CM*1024
cubemap_camera.height = CM*1024
cubemap_camera.zoom = 90.0

# # bind depth map buffer
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, depth_map_fbo)

# set viewport size to cubemap size
glViewport(0, 0, CM*1024, CM*1024)

# activate cubemap shader
cubemap_shader.use()

# create a projection matrix
projection = glm.perspective(glm.radians(90.0), 1.0, 0.1, 100)
cubemap_shader.set_uniform_mat4('projection', projection)

# RENDER TO DEPTH CUBEMAP
##########################
for i in range(6):

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X+i,
                           depth_cube_tex, 0)
    
    # all fine?
    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE):
        raise RuntimeError("ERROR.FRAMEBUFFER. Framebuffer is not complete!")

    # clear colors and buffers
    glClearColor(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT| GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    # rotate camera
    cubemap_camera.pitch = rotation_dict[i][0] #0
    cubemap_camera.yaw =  rotation_dict[i][1] #1
    cubemap_camera.update_camera_vectors()
    
    # update view (lookat matrix)?
    view = cubemap_camera.get_matrix_view()
    cubemap_shader.set_uniform_mat4('view',view)

    # load textures
    cube_texture = texture_from_file(pth, Path(r'textures/marble.jpg') )
    floor_texture = texture_from_file(pth, Path(r'textures/metal.png') )

    # render cubes
    glBindVertexArray(cube_vao)
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, cube_texture)

    # update projection and view matrices for display camera
    cubemap_shader.set_uniform_mat4('projection', projection)
    view = cubemap_camera.get_matrix_view() 
    cubemap_shader.set_uniform_mat4('view',view)

    # cube 1
    model = glm.mat4(1.0)
    model = glm.translate(model, glm.vec3(0.0, 0.0, -5.0))
    cubemap_shader.set_uniform_mat4('model', model)
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36)

    # cube 2
    model = glm.mat4(1.0)
    model = glm.translate(model, glm.vec3(-5.0, 0.0, 0.0))
    cubemap_shader.set_uniform_mat4('model', model)
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36)

    # cube 3
    model = glm.mat4(1.0)
    model = glm.translate(model, glm.vec3(0.0, 2.0, 0.0))
    cubemap_shader.set_uniform_mat4('model', model)
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36)

    glBindVertexArray(0) # remove binding

    # render floor
    glBindVertexArray(floor_vao)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, floor_texture)
    cubemap_shader.set_uniform_mat4('model', glm.mat4(1.0))
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6)
    glBindVertexArray(0) # remove binding

    # #output ?
    # zbuffer = glReadPixelsf(0, 0, CM*1024, CM*1024, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT)
    # zbuffer = zbuffer.reshape((CM*1024, CM*1024))
    # np.save(f'{rotation_dict[i][5]}_cube', np.flipud(zbuffer))

    glfw.swap_buffers(window)

# unbind fbo
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)
```

Last, sampling the cubemap just created. **This is the part that I am less certain**. How do I sample the cubemap in order to get the depth values for my 2D image. I am trying to do this using  shaders but I am not certain at all whether this are correct

```py
# SAMPLING CUBEMAP
##################

hangle = np.array([0,360,0.05], dtype=np.float32)
vangle = np.array([-90,0, 0.05], dtype=np.float32)

raw_width = (hangle[1]-hangle[0]) / hangle[2]
raw_height = (vangle[1]-vangle[0]) / vangle[2]

# create scene buffer
scene_buffer = glGenFramebuffers(1)
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, scene_buffer)

# attach a render buffer
rbo = glGenRenderbuffers(1)
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo)
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32, width, height)
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo)

if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE):
        raise RuntimeError("ERROR.FRAMEBUFFER. Framebuffer is not complete!")

# send information to sampling shader
cubemap_sampling_shader.use()
cubemap_sampling_shader.set_uniform_vec3('hangle', hangle)
cubemap_sampling_shader.set_uniform_vec3('vangle', vangle)
cubemap_sampling_shader.set_uniform_int('cubetex', depth_cube_tex)

# #output ?
zbuffer = glReadPixelsf(0, 0, width, height, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT)
zbuffer = zbuffer.reshape((height, width))
np.save('Scene', np.flipud(zbuffer))

glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0)
```

As mention all I get for 2D image (a numpy array) that is blank made out of 0s.

My shaders for the sampling are: vertex,

```
#version 330 core

uniform vec3 hangle; // horizontal angular range and increment
uniform vec3 vangle; // vertical angular range and increment
out vec3 dir_vector;


void main(){
    for (float theta = vangle.x; theta < float(vangle.y); theta+= vangle.z){
        for (float psi = hangle.x;  psi <  float(hangle.y); psi+= hangle.z){
            float x = sin(radians(theta)) * cos(radians(psi));
            float z = sin(radians(theta)) * sin(radians(psi));
            float y = cos(radians(theta));
            dir_vector = vec3(x,y,z);
        }
    } 
}
```

and fragment,

````
#version 330 core

in vec3 dir_vector;
uniform samplerCube cubetex;


void main(){
            gl_FragDepth = texture(cubetex, dir_vector).z;
}
```
````